# Documents required by broker for forex

Tags: access-control

I've registered for bitcoin forrex,paid the initial 250 USD,now they require that I sign a form giving access to my bank account,they also request a copy of my ID,proof of residence and banking as well as the front and back of my debit card. How legal is this if all they want to do is deposits?

Comment: Between legal questions and bitcoin, I don't think this is an Information Security question.

Comment: I don't think you're ever going to see that 250 dollars again.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, ask your bank, this is a steal-from-your-account question (:-))

Comment: This isn't really an answer. It's doesn't explain why. For example, a copy of an ID is very common for identification purposes. In Russia, nic.ru requires you give them a scanned photo ID, and they're not a scam. Though I do tend to agree with you that this sets of way too many red flags, especially the front and back of the debit card part.